# Python async vs Node.js async: how to execute an async function in Python and then continue until async is done?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the following script written in both js and python. However, I cannot get the python script to work.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function get_burgers() {
  console.log("Just ordered...");
  console.log("Making burgers");
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log("Burgers ready!");
  console.log("Eating them...");
}

async function main() {
  console.log("Walking into restaurant...");
  console.log("Ordering...");
  get_burgers();
  console.log("Talking, talking, talking...");
}

main();
```

This outputs:

```
Walking into restaurant...
Ordering...
Just ordered...
Making burgers
Talking, talking, talking...
Burgers ready!
Eating them...
```

This is the same script in `Python` using `asyncio`

```py
import asyncio


async def get_burgers():
    print("Just ordered...")
    print("Making burgers...")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Burgers ready!")
    print("Eating burgers")


async def main():
    print("Walking into store with crush")
    print("Ordering....")
    await asyncio.gather(get_burgers())
    print("Talking, talking, talking...")


asyncio.run(main())
```

This blocks and prints `Talking, talking, talking...` last. When I remove the `await` before `asyncio.gather(get_burgers())` it crashes. How would I make the python script give the result as the node.js script?

Answer (score 3):

The Python async model is a bit different – you'd need to do

```
import asyncio


async def get_burgers():
    print("Just ordered...")
    print("Making burgers...")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Burgers ready!")
    print("Eating burgers")


async def chat_while_waiting_for_burgers():
    print("Talking, talking, talking...")


async def main():
    print("Walking into store with crush")
    print("Ordering....")
    await asyncio.gather(get_burgers(), chat_while_waiting_for_burgers())


asyncio.run(main())
```

so the output is

```
Walking into store with crush
Ordering....
Just ordered...
Making burgers...
Talking, talking, talking...
Burgers ready!
Eating burgers
```

Comment: there isn’t  a way to fire the function without awaiting it?

Comment: @adirabargil You can call the function, but you do need to await for it eventually. There is no implicit loop like there is in Node.js that would "pump" all "remaining" coros.

Comment: You can create a task and await it at the end, but there is fire-and-forget behavior. The loop only runs as long as you’re awaiting something.

Answer (score 0):

may be also you can use _thread module

```
import _thread
import time

def get_burgers(x):
    print("Just ordered...")
    print("Making burgers...")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Burgers ready!")
    print("Eating burgers")
    print("Eating them")


def main(x):
    print("Walking into store with crush")
    print("Ordering....")
    _thread.start_new_thread( get_burgers, ("Thread-1", ) )
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Talking, talking, talking...")


try:
   _thread.start_new_thread( main, ("Thread-1", ) )
except:
   print ("Error: unable to start thread")

while 1:
   pass
```

output:

```
Walking into store with crush
Ordering....
Just ordered...
Making burgers...
Talking, talking, talking...
Burgers ready!
Eating burgers
Eating them
```

Comment: OP is explicitly asking about `async`, not threads. Additionally, if you want to use threads, you should never use `_thread` directly, but `threading`.

Comment: @AKX, he asking how to get with same result in python. CMIIW

Comment: They could get the same result without async or threading, but that's not the point. The title says "Python async", and the post says "The same script using Python asyncio".